# Bit invert function in K&R exercise 2-7

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, kernighan-and-ritchie

Exercise 2-7 of *The C Programming Language*:

> Write a function `invert(x,p,n)` that returns `x` with the `n` bits that begin at position `p` inverted (i.e., 1 changed to 0 and vice versa), leaving the others unchanged.

I understood the question like this: I have 182 which is `101(101)10` in binary, the part in parentheses has to be inverted without changing the rest. The return value should be `10101010` then, which is 170 in decimal.

Here is my attempt:

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned int getbits(unsigned int bitfield, int pos, int num);
unsigned int invert(unsigned int bitfield, int pos, int num);

int main(void)
{
    printf("%d\n", invert(182, 4, 3));
    return 0;
}

/* getbits: get num bits from position pos */
unsigned int getbits(unsigned int bitfield, int pos, int num)
{
    return (bitfield >> (pos+1-n)) & ~(~0 << num);
}

/* invert: flip pos-num bits in bitfield */
unsigned int invert(unsigned int bitfield, int pos, int num)
{
    unsigned int mask;
    unsigned int bits = getbits(bitfield,pos,num);

    mask = (bits << (num-1)) | ((~bits << (pos+1)) >> num);

    return bitfield ^ mask;
}
```

It seems correct (to me), but `invert(182, 4, 3)` outputs `536870730`. `getbits()` works fine (it's straight from the book). I wrote down what happens in the expression I've assigned to `y`:

```
(00000101 << 2) | ((~00000101 << 5) >> 3)    -- 000000101 is the part being flipped: 101(101)10
       00010100 | ((11111010 << 5) >> 3)
       00010100 | (01000000 >> 3)
       00010100 | 00001000
= 00011100

  10110110 (182)
^ 00011100
----------
= 10101010 (170)
```

Should be correct, but it isn't. I found out this is where it goes wrong: `((~xpn << (p+1)) >> n)`. I don't see how.

Also, I've no idea how general this code is. My first priority is to just get this case working. Help in this issue is welcome too.

Comment: Don't give rubbish names like "x, p, n" to your variables, that's a really bad idea.

Comment: @Lundin K&R named them such so I did as well. Although there may be formatting reasons behind that. I'll keep this in mind.

Comment: Yes, I realize that the really bad idea came from K&R. Be aware that you can't learn good programming practice from that book. You can only learn syntax from it, for a version of the C language that has been obsolete for 14 years.

Comment: @Lundin, those variable names are fine. K&R is **right**. By definition. Or look at the Linux kernel C style guide.

Comment: @vonbrand Err, no I'm sorry, but in modern programming there is no such thing as "right by definition because some guru said so in the 80s". In addition, programmers are expected to use their own brain. If you think that "x" is a great variable name, with or without using your brain, so be it - no further discussion after such a conclusion is pointless. As for the Linux kernel coding style, it is a rather informal document, lacking plenty of rationale or sources for the vague rules stated. It is certainly not some C canon. If you want a professional coding standard, look at MISRA-C or CERT-C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`((1u<<n)-1)` is a bit mask with `n` '1' bits at the RHS. `<<p` shifts this block of ones `p` positions to the left. (you should shift with `(p-n)` instead of p if you want to count from the left).

```
return val  ^ (((1u<<n)-1) <<p) ;
```

There still is a problem when p is larger than the wordsize (shifting by more than the wordsize is undefined), but that should be the responsability of the caller ;-)

For the example `101(101)10` with p=2 and n=3:

```
1u<<n               := 1000
((1u<<n)-1)         := 0111
(((1u<<n)-1) <<p) := 011100
original val    := 10110110
val ^ mask      := 10101010
```

Comment: What the first line is for? The condition holds for 0 as well

Comment: It is not needed. (I was afraid of the mask becoming all ones, but `(1<<0)-1` is all zeroos.

Comment: Doesn't seem to give the correct answer either. I now clarified how I understood the exercise in my question. Of course, I might have misunderstood it.

Comment: That is the `counting from the right` part. In your `101(101)10` example, I assumed p=2, and n=3.

Comment: @wildplasser I just realized I counted `p` correctly from the right but `n` from the left.

Comment: I always count from the right, because it is independent on the wordsize. wrt p: you *could* express your block_to_be_inverted as bitpostions := {2,3,4}; or 2 upto 5; or 4 downto 1; but that is confusing (and the latter would even cause negative values to arise.)

Answer (score 1):

I think you have an off-by-one issue in one of the shifts (it's just a hunch, I'm not entirely sure). Nevertheless, I'd keep it simple (I'm assuming the index position `p` starts from the LSB, i.e. `p`=0 is the **LSB**):

```
unsigned int getbits(unsigned int x, int p, int n) {
  unsigned int ones = ~(unsigned int)0;
  return x ^ (ones << p) ^ (ones << (p+n));
}
```

edit: If you need p=0 to be the **MSB**, just invert the shifts (this works correctly because `ones` is defined as `unsigned int`):

```
unsigned int getbits(unsigned int x, int p, int n) {
  unsigned int ones = ~(unsigned int)0;
  return x ^ (ones >> p) ^ (ones >> (p+n));
}
```

note: in both cases if `p < 0`, `p >= sizeof(int)*8`, `p+n < 0` or `p+n >= sizeof(int)*8` the result of `getbits` is undefined.

Comment: Doesn't give the correct value. I'm testing with 182 which is `101(101)10` - the part in parentheses is the part that should be inverted. The value I should be getting with `invert(182, 4, 3)` is 170.

Comment: That's because you're counting the **MSB** as p=0. I clearly stated that I'm counting the **LSB** as p=0. I'll fix my answer.

Comment: My mistake. I counted `p` from the right but `n` from the left.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Steve Summit's ["Introductory C programming"](http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/cclass.html) and at Ted Jensen's ["At tutorial on pointers and arrays in C"](http://pw1.netcom.com/~tjensen/ptr/pointers.htm). The language they cover is a bit different from today's C (also programming customs have evolved, machines are *much* larger, and real men don't write assembler anymore), but much of what they say is as true today as it was then. Sean Anderson's ["Bit twiddling hacks"](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ValueInWord) will make your eyes bulge. Guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was wrong in my implementation (other than counting `num` from the wrong direction). Seems fairly obvious afterwards now that I've learned more about bits.

When a 1-bit is shifted left, out of range of the bit field, it's expanded.

```
   1000 (8) << 1
== 10000 (16)
```

`bitfield << n` multiplies `bitfield` by 2 `n` times. My expression `((~bits << (pos+1)) >> num)` has 5, 4 and 3 as values for `bits`, `pos` and `num`, respectively. I was multiplying a number almost the size of a 32-bit int by 2, twice.

Answer (score 0):

how about my function? i think it so good.

```
unsigned invert(unsigned x,int p,int n)
{
     return (x^((~(~0<<n))<<p+1-n));
}
```